# Augmenting Object.prototype breaks Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, prototype

I came across an issue which might be a bug, or it might just be the intended functionality. I'm using a thirdparty script that is built with Dojo. In my own app I augment the Function.prototype and the Object.prototype with (for my app) handy utility functions. Including the thirdparty script always resulted in an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property _scopeName' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

After a while I realized it might lie in the fact that I augmented these prototypes. The Function.prototypes seemed to have no ill effect. But as soon as I removed all of my Object.prototype methods it stopped throwing the error.

A simple test setup

```
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        Object.prototype.foo = function() {
           console.log('bar');
        }
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this intended? And if so, would it not be better to then catch this error and throw a more meaningfull one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't do that.** :-)

You've added an enumerable property to `Object.prototype`, which means it shows up on **all objects** (via inheritance) in `for-in` loops and such:

```js
// DON'T DO THIS (see text for why)
Object.prototype.foo = function() {
  console.log("foo");
};

// Looping over an object
var obj = {
  myOwnProperty: "bar"
};
for (var key in obj) {
  snippet.log("obj['" + key + "']: " + obj[key]);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note that `foo` shows up in our loop. Now, often you would want a `hasOwnProperty` check in a `for-in` loop, but there times when you don't; adding enumerable properties to `Object.prototype` breaks the case where `hasOwnProperty` isn't appropriate.

Adding *anything* to `Object.prototype` is generally regarded as a very bad idea. Strongly recommend not doing it, at all.

But if you have a solid use case for it, define the property with a *very distinct name* and make it non-enumerable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "veryDistinctName", {
    value: function() {
        console.log("veryDistinctName");
    }
});
```

Properties defined by `defineProperty` are non-enumerable by default (also read-only by default), and so `veryDistinctName` won't show up in `for-in` loops and such:

```js
// *IF* you absolutely, positively *have* to define a new
// property on Object.prototype, make it non-enumerable:
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "veryDistinctName", {
  value: function() {
    console.log("veryDistinctName");
  }
});

// Looping over an object
var obj = {
  myOwnProperty: "bar"
};
for (var key in obj) {
  snippet.log("obj['" + key + "']: " + obj[key]);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

As you can see, `veryDistinctName` does not show in the loop.

---

> Is this intended?

Probably not explicitly, no. They just assumed you wouldn't augment `Object.prototype`.

> And if so, would it not be better to then catch this error and throw a more meaningfull one?

This is a matter of opinion, but: Probably not, it's a lot of extra overhead for very little benefit. In general, people know not to augment `Object.prototype`. If you do, so many things break so quickly you very quickly learn not to do it. So catering to that case is probably overkill.

That said, I could see an argument for one check when loading/initializing the library:

```
for (var key in {}) {
    throw new Error("Enumerable property '" + key + "' found on Object.prototype. Dojo doesn't support enumerable Object.prototype properties.");
}
```

You could still break it by adding to `Object.prototype` *later*, of course.

Comment: I can't stand adding `hasOwnProperty` around my for in loops. Would never use a library that augments Object. I stand on the side of overkill, just like avoiding `new`

Comment: @JuanMendes: Just use `Object.keys(obj).forEach(...)` :-) (it only does *own* enumerable properties).

Comment: That's slightly better. Not enough to change my mind yet :) However, if I were writing a library like Dojo, I would definitely add those checks